# How to make wireshark filter POST-requests only?

Tags: http, wireshark, filter, packet-capture, protocol-analyzer

How to make wireshark filter POST-requests only?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the following filter:

```
http.request.method == "POST"
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to display both methods GET and POST you filter wireshark like this

```
http.request.method == GET or http.request.method == POST
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sadashttp.request.method == “POST”
http.request.method == “POST”
```

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP2 just use `http2.headers.method == "POST"`